# I can't create a foreign key in my table - #1005

Tags: mysql, key, innodb

*#1005 - Can't create table 'forum.#sql-da8_f' (errno: 150)*

I keep getting this error when i want to apply a foreign key constraint to my table. I don't know what could be the problem. I learned that one will need to use an InnoDB to be able to use a FOREIGN KEY on Mysql. Doesn't that come with Mysql by default?

Btw, here

```
ALTER TABLE boards
ADD FOREIGN KEY (CategoryId)
REFERENCES categories(CategoryId)
```

EDIT:
Here's how i created my table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `boards` (
  `BoardId` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CategoryId` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `ChildLevel` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `ParentId` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `BoardOrder` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `LastMessageId` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `MessageUpdatedId` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `Groups` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `ProfileId` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `BoardName` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `BoardDescription` text,
  `NumberOfTopics` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `NumberOfPosts` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `CountPosts` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `HiddenPosts` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `HiddenTopics` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`BoardId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `BoardId` (`BoardId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

And here's my "categories" table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `CategoryId` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CategoryOrder` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `CategoryName` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`CategoryId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `CategoryId` (`CategoryId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=56 ;
```

Comment: How did you create your table?

Comment: Please provide more info. Show us your schema and/or create a http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: http://verysimple.com/2006/10/22/mysql-error-number-1005-cant-create-table-mydbsql-328_45frm-errno-150/

Comment: Check the edit. I added my table info.

Comment: We also need the schema of `categories`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that the types don't match: your primary key on `categories` is a `bigint unsigned` while your foreign key in `boards` is of type `int`. E.g. change the `boards` table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `boards` (
  `BoardId` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CategoryId` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  -- ...
)
```

[See this demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e5d6)

Comment: That did the match. I first changed the CategoryId on the board table to bigint just like tha categories but it didn't work until i also made it unsigned.